# Is it possible to create a PHP page that forces a file download and echoes a string?

Tags: php, echo, force-download

```
<?php
include "function.php";

$account = findSomeFile();
$file_url = '/var/www/html/tvconfig/netflix/'.$account.'.zip';
echo $account;

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\"");
readfile($file_url);

?>
```

Above is my PHP script. When I load the page I get the download prompt in the browser but there is no echo on the page. I have tried placing the echo after the readfile function but it does not work.

Comment: No, because a single http request can only have a single http response; a download and an echo would be two responses

Comment: If you want it to work somewhat like that, you can make an AJAX request from one page to the download page. Then it'll download the file and you'll stay on the same page. So for example, you can create another HTML page where you will write the stuff like "Your download has begun" while also making an AJAX request to the page.

Comment: And also that after sending out that echo your headers won't make any difference

Comment: @Janno I have avoided AJAX in my answer :)

Comment: @NehalJWani But you are using AJAX in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play a little trick:

```
<?php
$account = "38950596";
$file_url = "$account.json";
echo "Hello Friend!\n";

$fc = file_get_contents($file_url);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(e) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent('<?php echo $fc ?>'));
    pom.setAttribute('download', '<?php echo $account ?>');
    pom.click();
}
</script>
```

This will create a anchor element and as soon as the page loads, it will force a file download by using the click event.

Demo: http://main.xfiddle.com/e1a35f80/38950596_stackoverflow.php

Comment: As soon as your files are larger than a few megabyte this code will cause your server to implode, perhaps the client too…

Comment: @deceze OP was anyway going to use readfile($file_url); How would it make a difference then?

Comment: `readfile` directly streams from disk to output; `file_get_contents` first reads the file into memory in its entirety.

Comment: @deceze Ah, I see. Didn't know that :)

Comment: Then, shouldn't this answer be updated to use `readfile`?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked for me in 2024**

I know... I saw the year.. 2016 is a long time ago.
But maybe there is more people out there like me that stumble into this thread, and the solution from is inefficient and didnt work for me. So I 'm sharing this back to you, hoping it helps someone.

Ah, and if there is now yet a better way of doing this. Let me know.

```
<?php
$file_name = "vcard.vcf";
$file_url = "/usr/share/vcards_contacts/$file_name";

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(e) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/x-vcard;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(`<?php readfile($file_url)?>`));
    pom.setAttribute('download', '<?php echo $file_name ?>');
    pom.click();
}
</script>
```